# Arrays en formulario PHP Se actualiza y no se guardan

Tags: php, array, formularios

Sou nueva en php y me estoy volviendo un poco loca. Tengo que realizar una agenda de tareas donde si no hay tareas no aparece la lista y si añadimos una tarea aparezca la lista y luego se podran borrar o marcar como completadas. Mi codigo esta incompleto lo sé, pero el primer problema que me encuentro es que al añadir tareas se actualizan no se guardan y siempre me aparece solo la ultima añadida por el usuario, llevo un par de días dandole vueltas y no encuentro la solución.
Aquí dejo mi código hasta ahora ( sé que esta incompleto) ( esta en formulario y el php todo junto por que me lo piden así)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                    <label for="nuevatarea">Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nuevatarea" name="nuevatarea[]"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit">Añadir Tarea</button>
                    <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
            <br>
            <?php 
                if(!$_POST){
            ?>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                    <label id="vacio">No hay tareas</label>
                </fieldset>  
            </div>
            <br>
            <?php 
                }else {
        ?>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                    <?php 
                        echo "<ol>";
                            foreach ($_POST["nuevatarea"] as $nuevatarea) {
                                echo"<li> $nuevatarea </li>";
                            }
                        echo"</ol>"
                    ?>
                </fieldset>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="tarea">Num Tarea:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="tarea" name="tarea"/>
                    <button type="button"id="completarTarea"> Tarea Completada</button>
                    <input type="button" id="borrarTarea" value="Tarea Borrada"/>
                    <br><!-- comment -->
                    <input type="button" id="vaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
       
       
        <?php
                }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: En la programación el almacenamiento es volátil. ¿Qué quiere decir eso? Que a no ser que persistas la información de alguna manera (en una base de datos, en localstorage, en una cookie...) al finalizar la ejecución de tu script, ya no va a existir. La página que tienes desarrollada tiene 2 estados. El primero es cuando llegas a ella por primera vez, el segundo cuando llegas a ella junto a la información enviada a través del formulario. Cada vez que añades una nueva tarea llegas a través de la segunda y $_POST solamente tiene la información del formulario que acabas de enviar.

Comment: siguiendo tu consejo guarde los datos en un sessions. pero ahora me da otro error que no se porque.. funcionar funciona pero me alterna los datos que voy guardando. Al rellenar con numeros para que me entiendas  al poner 1 le doy añadir me sale pero si añado el 2 se borra el 1 y si pongo 3 ssale la lista de 1 y3.

Comment: Inspeccionado el elemento veo que el value del input hidden que meto enel primer envio no se guarda el 1 hasta que le damos una segunda vez a aenviar

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal es ocupar Base de datos, pero supongo que esto es un ejercicio.

Hay muchas maneras de hacer esto como utilizar variables de session. Pero tu en algún lado tienes name="nuevatarea[]"

Cuando pones unos corchetes [] al final de un atributo name lo conviertes en un array, es decir una lista de nombres de tareas.

Donde tú lo tienes está mal, pero la idea es buena. La cual es básicamente hacer una bola de nieve de inputs. Es decir ingresas el primero, y lo retornas en la lista de abajo, ingresas el segundo y lo sumas a esa lista y así sucesivamente.  y cada vez que envías algo por POST envías la nueva tarea y la lista de tareas antiguas. Para esto la etiqueta form tiene que cubrir tanto el nuevo input como los viejos

Ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Agenda de Tareas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Agenda de Tareas</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Nueva Tarea:</legend>
                <?php // nueva tarea el name va sin [] ?>
                <label for="nuevatarea">Tarea:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nuevatarea" name="nuevatarea" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <button type="submit">Añadir Tarea</button>
                <button type="reset">Limpiar Campos</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>


        <br />
        
        <?php if( $_POST ) : ?>
          
        <div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <?php // agregamos la nueva tarea ahora si con  [] ?>
                        <input type="text" name="tareas[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['nuevatarea']; ?>" readonly />
                    </li>
                    <?php foreach ($_POST["tareas"] as $tareas) : ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php // listamos las tareas antiguas ?>
                        <input type="text" name="tareas[]" value="<?php echo $tareas; ?>" readonly/ />
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Lista Tareas:</legend>
                    <label id="vacio">No hay tareas</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <br />
   
 
 
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="tarea">Num Tarea:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tarea" name="tarea" />
            <button type="button" id="completarTarea"> Tarea Completada</button>
            <input type="button" id="borrarTarea" value="Tarea Borrada" />
            <br /><!-- comment -->
            <input type="button" id="vaciar" value="Vaciar Agenda" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```